# Rounding double

Tags: java, double, rounding

```
double x = 0.54;
double y = 0.06;
System.out.println("Dimmer: " + (x+y));
```

gives me the output:

```
Dimmer: 0.6000000000000001
```

Could someone elaborate this for me.

Comment: You are seeing a rounding error.  To avoid seeing this, use BigDecimal, or round your result. e.g. `System.out.printf("Dimmer: %.2f%n", x + y);`